# Error: "Invalid controller class: display"

Tags: administrator, login, joomla-4

I've installed Joomla 4 to test with, and I'm getting this error on every attempt to login to the admin:

> Invalid controller class: display

I've re-installed and am using the latest alpha release.

Any ideas of how to fix?

Comment: Please report any J4 bugs on the Joomla Issue Tracker: https://github.com/joomla/joomla-cms/issues

Comment: This question may be Too Broad because we don't have any details regarding your environment.

Comment: Are you installing on local or on a server somewhere?

Comment: Check that `libraries/autoload_psr4.php` file exists.